# Express.js send post request another url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, blockchain

I'm trying send post request to http://http://localhost:5555//transactions/new with body

```
{
     "from": faucetAddress,
     "to": userAddres,
     "value": 5,
     "senderPubKey": faucetPublicKey,
     "senderSignature": ["e20c…a3c29d3370f79f", "cf92…0acd0c132ffe56"]
}
```

This is the code that i'm using -
https://github.com/blockchain-dev-camp/blockchain-faucet
get in controllers/faucet-controller.js and then in postTransaction.

Comment: Great! And what is your question?

Comment: I don't know how to send post request form this express web app to another web app.

Comment: First you should not stringify your json - just add `json: postData` in your `options` object. This also sets the Content-Type header automatically.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful? https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: Thank you that was really useful!